# Microsoft Office table of contents - Displaying cutdown of headers?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have a header (and many similar):

```
 List<Services> GetServices(Int32 CostCentreNo, Int32 Filter);
```

But is there any way to ignore things inside the parentheses or any way of making it auto-add something smaller? I.e., the contents page containing just

```
 GetServices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Style Separator](http://pubs.logicalexpressions.com/pub0009/lpmarticle.asp?id=177) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

See also this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285050).

[Here is an example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62722148/img/se/doc/TOC_Example.doc). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to see invisible characters.